# C++ locale with get_time_byname vs hardcoded

Tags: c++, time

Which one is the best practice:

- `std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), new std::time_get_byname<char>("en_US"))`
- or `std::locale("en_US.UTF8")` ?

The context is when this used in e.g. `sstream::imbue`.